# Vipermonkey/ cannot import from logger import log and from core.meta import get_metadata.exif error. How can I solve them?

Tags: python, computer-forensics, monkey, viper

When I run the command "C:\Users\X\ViperMonkey-master\vipermonkey>python vmonkey.py -f C:\Users\X\Desktop\Example.docx", I get the following error. How can I solve it?

```
C:\Users\X\ViperMonkey-master\vipermonkey>python vmonkey.py -f C:\Users\X\Desktop\Example.docx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\ViperMonkey-master\vipermonkey\vmonkey.py", line 44, in <module>
    from core.meta import get_metadata_exif
  File "C:\Users\X\ViperMonkey-master\vipermonkey\core\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from logger import log
ImportError: cannot import name 'log' from 'logger' (C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\logger\__init__.py)
```

I tried changing the name of the C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\logger_*init*_.py to "**init**__.py" but it didn't fix the problem.